# Red5 server: NetConnection.Connect.Closed

Tags: linux, red5, red5-recorder

I have installed Red5 server (0.9.1) on the Linux server, but I am  having some problems to install any app on my Red5 server using the installer.

The front page (http://my.ip:5080) works great, but when I try to go to the installer (http://my.ip:5080/installer), I get an error message like this:

> Trying to connect
>   Net status: NetConnection.Connect.InvalidApp
>   Net status:NetConnection.Connect.Closed

Comment: That's telling you that the flash portion of the installer application is not loaded / installed or simply didnt start up. Check your logs.

Comment: how can we open flash portion -1935 in linux server?

Comment: 1935 is opened by default, make sure no other apps are binding to the port. Again, check the logs.